# solr multiple tokenizers for query

Tags: lucene, solr, tokenize

I am rather new to SolR. I would like to use multiple tokenizers.

I am using the standard tokenizer so that words get split via \t, space, comma, etc.

Now I would like to use an additional tokenizer.

If there is the word

"cowshed"

I would like it to become "cow" and "shed".

There are only I few words which are common to the search index which I would like to split.

Therefore I planned using the regex tokenizer. However I get an error message when I try to ("multiple tokenizers at xml root").

Is it not possible? Do I need to change the code? Am I doing it wrong?

Thanks for your hints :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one [tokenizer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Tokenizers) per analyzer. If you need to modify the tokens generated by the tokenizer you can use [token filters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Token_Filters).

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I now simply send "cowshed" through the synonyme filter, definining "cowshed => cow shed". Thanks!