# SOLR EdgeNGramFilter return wrong response

Tags: solr, lucene

Query: mpn:"MEM-CF-512MB-AOK"

Solr response:

```
{
"responseHeader": {
"status": 0,
"QTime": 1,
"params": {
  "fl": "id, mpn, name",
  "indent": "true",
  "q": "mpn:\"MEM-CF-512MB-AOK\"",
  "_": "1375801439480",
  "wt": "json"
}
},
"response": {
"numFound": 2,
"start": 0,
"docs": [
  {
    "id": "1340120",
    "mpn": "MEM-CF-256MB-AOK",
    "name": "256MB CompactFlash"
  },
  {
    "id": "1340129",
    "mpn": "MEM-CF-512MB-AOK",
    "name": "512MB CompactFlash"
  }
  ]
},
"spellcheck": {
  "suggestions": [
  "correctlySpelled",
  true
]
 }
}
```

expected:

```
 {
        "id": "1340129",
        "mpn": "MEM-CF-512MB-AOK",
        "name": "512MB CompactFlash"
      }
```

I need search:

1)MEM-CF-512MB-AOK

2)MEM-CF-512MB

3)MEM-CF-512MB-AO

4)M-CF-512MB-AOK

5) -CF-512MB-AOK

schema.xml:

```
<field name="mpn" type="text_general_edge_ngram" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<fieldType name="text_general_edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="50" side="front"/>
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LowercaseTokenizer` is functionality equivalent to a `LetterTokenizer` and `LowercaseFilter`.  Judging by the case you've provided, you don't want `LetterTokenizer`-like functionality, which will only index consecutive sets of letters.  Effectively, before the Ngramming, you have the tokens:

```
mem, cf, mb, aok
```

I think what you want is a `KeywordTokenizer` and `LowercaseFilter`

Since you want to be able to search with missing characters at the end as well as the beginning, you need to perform a prefix query.  An EdgeNgramTokenizer only produces NGrams taking characters off the front, such as:

```
mem-cf-512mb-aok, em-cf-512mb-aok, m-cf-512mb-aok, -cf-512mb-aok
```

So, to pick up matches with missing characters at the end, a simple prefix search should work, like:

`m-cf-512mb-a*`

`minGramSize="1"` is almost certainly overzealous.  You don't likely want 1-grams (ie. matching just `"k"`).  Your minimal case above would is 12 in length, for instance.  I'll guess 5 for a reasonable min gram size.

```
<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowercaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="5" maxGramSize="50" side="front"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowercaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

And again, you should use queries appended with a trailing wildcard.

Comment: I get an error with this:
<tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
<tokenizer class="solr.LowercaseFilterFactory"/>
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4997599/397862

Comment: Sure, minor copy-paste error.  You can't use a filter as a tokenizer.  Might benefit from reading the [Solr description of Analyzers](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Analyzers)

Comment: sorry, i'm new in solr.
thanks, query "mpn:*-cf-512mb-a*" works fine, but query time very  
high "QTime": 2466, Why is that?

Comment: Lucene doesn't handle leading wildcards well.  Since it looks up matches by term values, a leading wildcard causes it to scan every term, rather than being able to narrow it down significantly.  Trailing wildcards do not have the same problem.  That why EdgeNGramFilter is often used to provide leading wildcard searching, while a simple wildcard query can handle trailing ones with very little impact on performance.  Another strategy is to also index the reversed string, useful when only leading OR trailing wildcards (not both) will be needed in the same query.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you've described looks like an exact match on `mpn` field.

However, you've defined `mpn` as Edge-NGram with mingram=1. This will start indexing 1-gram onwards. Which isn't what you would need, I imagine.

In order to get this sorted, I guess you could have another field (if you want NGram for another reason ) and have your exact query match against it. Ex

```
mpn_exact:"MEM-CF-512MB-AOK"
```

You could test this out by using the **Analysis** component of your Admin console.

Comment: if i use mpn_exact with type text_general, i can't find docs for this query: mpn:"EM-CF-512MB-A"